# Algbraic proof of compound periodicity of a function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

While studying trigonometric functions I keep encountering exercises of this sort:

> $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\tan\left(x\right)}{1+\sin\left(x\right)}$. Show that the periodicity of $f(x)$ is $2\pi $.

I have looked on the Internet and the most I could find was stating that since the periodicity of $\textbf{tan} =\pi$ and the periodicity of $\textbf{sin}=2\pi$, then the compound periodicity is $2\pi$. But why?

I'm learning Math all by myself, so I really can't afford to just memorize algorithms and formulas. Could you provide me with a thorough explanation of the process by which I can arrive at such conclusions? I would mostly value and algebraic proof.

Comment: Do you understand why $f(x) = f(x + 2\pi)$, i.e. $2\pi$ is *a* period of $f$?

Comment: Yes, I do. You get back to where you've started. I've a rather good intuitive notion of that concept. So maybe I'm not connecting the dots? But where?

Comment: What do you mean "you get back to where you've started"? The periodicity $\tau$ of a function $f$ is the least positive real such that $f(x + \tau) = f(x)$ for all $x$. Showing that it is true for $\tau = 2\pi$ is half the work (but the easy part); now you have to show that it doesn't hold for a number smaller than $2\pi$.

Comment: I understand, the period is a number that if you add it to any $x$ in $f(x)$ you obtain the same value in $y$.

Comment: The periodicity of a compound function is when all functions provide the same value - this happens when usually after the longest periods. There are expressions that will result a shorter period but the "worst" is as described above.